# Rails 4 live streaming updates to a bootstrap table row updated with in-place editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, synchronization, datatables, server-sent-events, best-in-place

Although I have probably bookmarked every question on this site, I pretty much never post my own questions because I’m afraid of a snarky response. So, apologies in advance if I’m overlooking something totally obvious or simply approaching this the wrong way, but I’ve gotten to the end of the Internet and my head is officially spinning so I’m calling for reinforcements from the Rails community.

I would appreciate any advice on a good way to continually refresh rows in a data table in my Rails 4 app.

The original problem I was trying to remedy is that my coworkers needed simultaneous access to a monthly-generated Excel document. I strongly dislike Excel so I created a better version of those documents in a Rails 4 app that my coworkers now edit simultaneously.

The problem I am currently trying to fix is that they need to see each other’s updates in real time. Table cells are updated by my coworkers (40 simultaneous users max) on my company’s internal webapp. (A Google Spreadsheet is not a viable solution because the data is relational and is much better maintained in my mySql database.)

This is one of my first Rails apps but it’s come a long way since Hello World. At its current state I’m using Rails 4.1.6 and JQuery dataTables combined with the best_in_place gem for in-place editing.

The app is working fine for now but I keep getting emails about dependent cells not updating when new data is entered in other cells in the same row (my coworkers are used to their data being in Excel format and seeing one cell update instantly based on whatever formula). I’m tired of (and honestly embarrassed by) telling them to “refresh the page” to fix their problems. Moreover, I want everyone to be able to see the updates in real time.

I’ve tried the [sync gem](https://github.com/chrismccord/sync) (using Faye and Thin), but I cannot for the life of me get it to work in any environment and there are literally only two tutorials ([sync_example](https://github.com/chrismccord/sync_example) and [RailsConf video with no code](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/3331-railsconf-real-time-rails-with-sync)), neither of which explain how to implement it in a production environment.

I’m currently using Server-Sent Events/EventSource via ActionController::Live (with Puma and Nginx) per [TenderLove's Is it live? blog post](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html). The problem with this approach is that I'm not able to close the connection after the client disconnects or navigates to another page so all my database connections are being used up and then the db connection is blocked. [This seems to be a known issue for many others](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10989#issuecomment-23114944) but I'm wondering if maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way altogether.

Could the constant looping be a problem? If I changed it back to n.times, won't I lose the connection and just be back at square one??

Here’s my code. #products is my jQuery dataTable and each row is rendered in a partial with unique id.

in my products/show view:

```
         <tbody>
            <% @products.each do |product| %>
              <%= render partial: '/products/product', :collection => @products %>    
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
. . .
<script type='text/javascript'>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var source = new EventSource('/application/events');
      source.addEventListener('refresh_product_row', function(event) {
        var id = JSON.parse(event.data).id;
        $.getScript('/products/show.js?id=' + id);
        $('#products').dataTable();
      });
    }, 1);
  });

</script>
```

show.js.erb

```
$('#products tbody #product_row_<%= @product.id %>').hide();
$('#products tbody #product_row_<%= @product.id %>').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(raw render(:partial => "products/product", :object => @product))%>');
$('#products tbody #product_row_<%= @product.id %>').fadeIn('slow');
// Re-activating Best In Place
$('.best_in_place').best_in_place();
```

in my application controller:

```
def events
  unless ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'development'
    # SSE expects the `text/event-stream` content type
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'

    sse = Reloader::SSE.new(response.stream)
    start = Time.zone.now

    begin
      # 10.times do
      loop do
        Product.uncached do
          Product.where('updated_at > ?', start).each do |product|
            # data will be streamed to the client every time we call the write method.
            sse.write({ :id => product.id }, :event => 'refresh_product_row')
            sleep 0.0001
            start = product.updated_at
          end
        end
        sleep 1
      end
      render nothing: true
    rescue IOError
      # When the client disconnects, we'll get an IOError on write
      logger.info "Client disconnected. Stream closed"
    ensure
      sse.close
    end
  end
end
```

and in /lib/reloader/sse.rb

```
require 'json'

module Reloader
  class SSE
    def initialize io
      @io = io
    end

    def write object, options = {}
      options.each do |k,v|
        @io.write "#{k}: #{v}\n"
      end
      @io.write "data: #{JSON.dump(object)}\n\n"
    end

    def close
      @io.close
    end
  end
end
```

Please let me know if you need any more info. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of code to paste here so check this code out, I just paste the table code of mine, the rest you do as in the tutorial 
https://melvinchng.github.io/rails/ActionCable.html#21-initial-setup

index.html.erb

```
<h1>All Leaderboard Entries</h1> 
   <div class='container-fluid'> 
      <div class='row py-3 px-3'>
        <div class='col-12 col-sm-8'> 
          <table id='entry-table' class="table table-hover">
            <thead  class="thead-light">
              <tr>
                <th>Leaderboard</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Score</th>
                <th colspan="3"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead> 
          <tbody id="leaderboard_entries"> 
             <%= render @leaderboard_entries.presence || 'leaderboard_entry' %> 
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

_leaderboard_entries.html.erb

```
  <tr>
    <td><%= leaderboard_entry.leaderboard.name%></td>
    <td><%= leaderboard_entry.username %></td>
    <td><%= leaderboard_entry.score %></td>
    <td><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-eye" style="color:blue"></i> Show '.html_safe, leaderboard_entry %></td>
    <td><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-edit" style="color:orange"></i> Edit '.html_safe, edit_leaderboard_entry_path(leaderboard_entry,  :return_to=>"leaderboard_entries") %></td>
    <td><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-trash" style="color:red"></i> Destroy'.html_safe, leaderboard_entry, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
```